# reading xml from a jsp file

Tags: java, xml, jsp

So I am trying to read a xml from a jsp page. It works but it seems like it's really picky with the path of the .xml file i'm reading.

```
<%
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse("new.xml");

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

%>

Redirecting it to the xml file on my hard drive works fine but whenever I try to redirect it to the .xml file on the application, i keep getting path file not found, malformed url exception, etc. I even tried putting it in the WEB-INF to see if it can read from there but it can't.

Is there a way to do it or it's impossible?

Comment: Not impossible , put jsp and xml in webinf and use "new.xml" or ".\new.xml"

Comment: What do you mean by " I try to redirect it to the .xml file on the application"?

Comment: the xml file is in the application, so i'm trying to access the xml in the same location as the jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

You *must* have to create Java class (Servlet or model class) to parse the `XML` document. In your code-snippet you *must* have to specify the real path of XML document and method `ServletContext.getRealPath(virtualPath)` will be used get real path from virtual path.

Your code in Servelt shold be,

```
String realPath=getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/new.xml"); or "/new.xml"
```

and in JSPs you can use implicit object - `application.getRealPath(string)` .